# need to select all data based on year and month

Tags: javascript, php, date

I want to select data from sql based on year and month that have chosen by user. But the result doesnt show the correct output. It is just show a list of all data from database.

Can someone help me to fix my code

```
<div class="actions" style="margin-top: 8px;">
        <div style=" float: left; background-color: #EAEAEA; padding: 9px 9px 9px 9px; color: black; width: 21em;">
                <b>Silahkan pilih tahun dan bulan terlebih dahulu !!</b>
        </div>
        <div style="float:right;">
        <select id="tahun" name="tahun" class='download-data' style="width: 12em" onChange="getPages(this.value)">
            <option value="">-- Pilih Tahun--</option>
            <?php
            $tahun = $db->query("select concat(year(tgl_pemeriksaan),'-',month(tgl_pemeriksaan),'-01') tahun from tbl_pemeriksaan group by concat(year(tgl_pemeriksaan)) order by tgl_pemeriksaan desc");
                for ($i = 0; $i < count($tahun); $i++) {
                    if (date("Y", strtotime($_GET[''])) == date("Y", strtotime($tahun[$i]['tahun']))) {
                        echo '<option value="'.$tahun[$i]['tahun'].'" selected>'.date("Y", strtotime($tahun[$i]['tahun'])).'</option>';
                    }
                    else {
                        echo '<option value="'.$tahun[$i]['tahun'].'">'.date("Y", strtotime($tahun[$i]['tahun'])).'</option>';
                    }
                }
            ?>
        </select>
        <select id="bulan" name="bulan" class='download-data' style="width: 12em" onChange="getPages(this.value)">
            <option value="">-- Pilih Bulan --</option>
            <?php
            $bulan = $db->query("select concat(year(tgl_pemeriksaan),'-',month(tgl_pemeriksaan),'-01') bulan from tbl_pemeriksaan group by concat(month(tgl_pemeriksaan)) order by tgl_pemeriksaan desc");
                for ($i = 0; $i < count($bulan); $i++) {
                    if (date("F", strtotime($_GET[''])) == date("F", strtotime($bulan[$i]['bulan']))) {
                        echo '<option value="'.$bulan[$i]['bulan'].'" selected>'.date("F", strtotime($bulan[$i]['bulan'])).'</option>';
                    }
                    else {
                        echo '<option value="'.$bulan[$i]['bulan'].'">'.date("F", strtotime($bulan[$i]['bulan'])).'</option>';
                    }
                }
            ?>
        </select>
```

here is to get data from sql :

```
<?php
            $data = $db->query("SELECT a.*, b.* FROM tbl_pasien a inner join tbl_pemeriksaan b on a.id = b.id_pasien where month(b.tgl_pemeriksaan)='".date("m", strtotime($_GET['id']))."' and year(b.tgl_pemeriksaan)='".date("Y", strtotime($_GET['id']))."' order by tgl_pemeriksaan desc", 0); 
                for ($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++) {
            ?>
```

and here is my javascript code :

```
<script language="javascript">
        function getPages(id) {
        window.location = "index.php?mod=data&submod=download_data&id=" + id;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: To filter data, you need to use `WHERE` clause, which is missing from your queries.

Comment: it is not missed it is in lowercase

Comment: can you print_r or var_dump $query before doing itself?. 
you can use something alike this code to catch the sql query to debug.
`$data = ("SELECT a.*, b.* FROM tbl_pasien a inner join tbl_pemeriksaan b on a.id = b.id_pasien where month(b.tgl_pemeriksaan)='".date("m", strtotime($_GET['id']))."' and year(b.tgl_pemeriksaan)='".date("Y", strtotime($_GET['id']))."' order by tgl_pemeriksaan desc", 0);
print_r($data);die;`